# refreshing components from within another component in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, router-outlet

I will try to keep this simple and as concise as possible.

We are using Angular 4. Normally the solution would be to add watchers in previous versions but these are no longer around so require a bit of real world knowledge on implementing a solution to what is likely a simple issue.

We have 3 components within our main.ts file

```
<header_component></header_component>
<router_outlet></router_outlet>
<footer_component></footer_component>
```

So we are having issues when it comes to refreshing the views(components) on log on and log off.

On "logon" a separate router_outlet is used and on successful login we navigate to the user table and this causes the init to reload the users. however as this is only changing the router_outlet the header does not refresh to display the now "logout" and "reset password" options. So the solution for this would need to trigger a refresh on the headed_component as well as the router_outlet.

The second issue is that on "logoff" this is done within the header_component so the options in the header change to "login" and "Forgot Password". The issue this time is that the router_outlet does not refresh to remove the additional functionality that logging in gives you to (Edit, Delete, Add) users.

I have looked at the Angular.io and the documentation doesn't really cover the setup that we are using. Granted that could just be my interpretation of it.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Lewis

UPDATE:
Okay so i have been making some progress on this however i have hit a bit of a dead end

I have implemented the observable concept

headerComponent has
`constructor(private _loginService: LoginService, private _authService: AuthService) {
       this.isLoggedIn = _loginService.getLoggedInStatus.subscribe((loggedIn: boolean) => this.changeLoggedInStatus(loggedIn));
}`

the usercomponent also has much the same

The loginService has
  ` export class LoginService {
   @Output() getLoggedInStatus: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

```
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (currentUser) {
        this.getLoggedInStatus.emit(true);
        return (true) as any;
    } else {
        this.getLoggedInStatus.emit(false);
        return (false) as any;
    }
}
```

On logout i fire `this.getLoggedInStatus.emit(false)` but this is not being received by the usercomponent

any ideas?

Comment: You mention the docs not covering your setup, but does https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service not provide a pattern you can adopt?

Comment: So that is fine for reporting up however there is no Parent-child link between the Header component and components loaded by the Router_outlet. This is where the issue appeared. We have looked at using the ChangeDetectorRef which seems more suitable however we hit issues with implementing this. 

This is why i was suggesting a real world example.

Comment: Yes, which is *exactly why you communicate via a service*.

Comment: As i mentioned i may have interpreted the doc wrong and misread it so i will take this on board and give it a go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a service which will return you the user status i:e whether the user is logged in or not.

```
isLoggedIn(){
  return true //if user is logged in
   or
  return false // if the user is not logged in 
}
```

Then in your header component you can call this service to check the user status and set a flag based on the response

```
userFlag = serviceName.isLoggedIn();
```

in your html file use this flag to display the desired labels based on the userflag
i:e if userFlag is true (user logged in) then

```
<div *ngIf="userFlag">  
    display "logout" and "reset password" 
</div>
<div *ngIf="!userFlag">
     display "login" and "forgot password" 
</div>
```

You can also give a try to Angular Obsevables

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is similar to what we have so its good to know im along the right lines with that. I will implement the service based on both your answer and @jonrsharpe suggestion and will update later

Comment: So I have implemented the service and wired this up. However the issue is still there, where the DOM is not being updated. Any ideas on how to trigger  the DOM to update?

Comment: You can try observable concept where you can subscribe to a change and modify the content accordingly. It will be helpful to you in future as well.

Comment: Ended up using Observables with subscribes and emits

Comment: you will find rxjs library very handy in development.